# Limitation of adding years in dateoffset pandas

Tags: pandas

This is reference to other question i found on SO, but i am not intersted add the reference here without their permission. My question is what will be the reason for i cannot add more than 240 years to pandas dataframe with pd.offsets.DateOffset?. Because i cannot find any documenation or relavant answers.

Here is my code

```
df=pd.date_range(start="2020-10-29",end="2020-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['dte'])
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=241)
```

Output is

```
    dte dte_
0   2020-10-29  2261-10-29
1   2020-10-30  2261-10-30

df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=242)
```

The output of above code is

```
dte dte_
0   2020-10-29  1678-04-09 00:25:26.290448384
1   2020-10-30  1678-04-10 00:25:26.290448384
```

If i change start and end date to 2021 as follows

```
df=pd.date_range(start="2021-10-29",end="2021-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()
```

I am able to add only 240 years

```
df=pd.date_range(start="2200-10-29",end="2200-10-30").to_pydatetime().tolist()
df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['dte'])
df["dte_"]=df["dte"]+pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=62)
```

Output is

```
dte dte_
0   2200-10-29  1678-04-09 00:25:26.290448384
1   2200-10-30  1678-04-10 00:25:26.290448384
```

1. Is this due to limitation of availability calender date after 240 Years from now?
2. Or pandas Limitation?
3. Or is this my misunderstanding about DateOffset?
4. I undestand **2261** Supposed to be the last year. Is there any speciality for **2261**?

Comment: I do got the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds of Timestamp are:

- `Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')`
- `Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')`

You can find additional information [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units)

Comment: Thanks for your response, let me go through